# is it a bad idea to let my tortoise explore my room while supervised?

Tags: cats, safety, aggression, tortoises, habitat

I let my tortoise wander around my room to let out his energy(if I don't he gets restless and antsy). I was wondering if I need to have the humidity/temperature up in my room? also, some of my cats keep trying to eat him, so I have to keep them out of my room while he is wandering around. are there any ways to discourage this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he's out for a short period of time (a few hours max), you shouldn't worry about the temperature/humidity.

As for the cats, I personally have never had one but it may be likely that it can't be changed/discouraged and is too dangerous to try.